# Disable or enable collisions based on object tag Unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to disable or enable collision with object in unity 2d game based on its tag. Lets say I have object with tag "foo1" and objects with tag "foo2". If user choose to collide with objects "foo1" then it should not collide with objects "foo2".

How could I achieve this? I tried this:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Object other)
 {
      if (other.tag == "foo1")
          collider.enabled = false;
 }
```

But this is not working for two reasons. First object has to have isTrigger set to true (this could not be set for objects that serves as ground) and if I disable entire collider then object will fall through ground.

I am new to unity and I will study it in more details but I am asking for quick help and maybe idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing this via tags, you might want to [have a look at layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html).

By assigning different objects to different layers, you can set them to either collide with each other, or ignore any potential collisions. You can achieve this at

> Edit->Project Settings->Physics

where you can edit the layer collision matrix, to enable or disable collisions between layer elements.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of trouble