# How to ignore colliding on an object in Unity (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 5 objects in my game and 2 "frames". I would like 1 of the objects to collide with the inner frame, but not the 4 another one. I have attached box collider to the frames, and circle colliders to the 5 objects. My problem is that I don't want the 4 objects to collide with the inner frame just with the outer one. Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried creating different layers, assigning your objects/frames to different layers, and choosing which layers collide with each other? See `Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D` for a collision matrix, as well as `Edit > Project Settings > Tags and Layers` to create your layers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable or enable collisions based on object tag Unity 2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292705/disable-or-enable-collisions-based-on-object-tag-unity-2d)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who couldn't find a solution for this problem:
If your child object's collider is a trigger and your parent object's collider is not, then you can check the collisions in the OnCollisionEnter method. If you still want to do something with other collider, then you can do it in the OnTriggerEnter method. That seperates two colliders into two different functions. This helped me because my child object was a trigger, I hope this solution helps others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the page, from the official guide, that explains how to use the Collision Matrix. This is the right way to approach your problem: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html

Basically, you go under **Edit->Project Settings->Physics**, and you define the rules for the layers' collision. Then, you just need to assign a layer to each object.

Answer (score 0):

For those having this problem, It appears to be that if your parent has a RidgidBody any child collider will trigger the collision.

I solved this by adding a RidgidBody to my child, this avoids the inheritance from the parent.